# SOAP with PHP to SAP Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

So what I am trying to do in our enterprise environment is to connect to an SAP Web Service using the PHP class SoapClient in wsdl mode.

So far what I accomplished is getting "missing property" errors. Upon resolving all missing property errors I am getting the dreaded http error 500 with the body: soap-env:Server

So this is my code:

```
class SapTest {
 const SAP_WSDL_URI  = *wsdl_uri*;
 const SAP_USER = *username*;
 const SAP_PWD  = *password*;

public function execute() {

        $client = new SoapClient('http://'.urlencode(self::SAP_USER).':'.urldecode(self::SAP_PWD).'@'.self::SAP_WSDL_URI,
                array("trace" => 1,
                      "exceptions" => 1,
                      "login" => self::SAP_USER,
                      "password" => self::SAP_PWD,
                      'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS)
        );

        $method = '_-bic_-nf2';

        $parameter = array('ETColumnDescription' => null,
                           'ETGridData' => null,
                           'ETMessageLog' => null,
                           'ETRowDescription' => null,
                           'ISVar_01xwerbet' => array('Sign' => 'I',
                                                      'Option' => 'LE',
                                                      'Low' => '3',
                                                      'High' => null));

        try
        {

        $result = $client->$method($parameter);
        print_r($result);
        } catch(SoapFault $e) {

        echo "REQUEST HEADER:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
          echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";

          echo "RESPONSE HEADER:\n" . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() . "\n";

          echo "RESPONSE:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
        print_r($e);
    }


}

}

$oSap = new SapTest();
$oSap->execute();
```

my xml output looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:_-bic_-nf2>
   <ETColumnDescription/>
   <ETGridData/>
   <ETMessageLog/>
   <ETRowDescription/>
   <ISVar_01xwerbet>
    <Sign>I</Sign>
    <Option>LE</Option>
    <Low>3</Low>
    <High/>
   </ISVar_01xwerbet>
  </ns1:_-bic_-nf2>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

the expected xml should look as follow:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <urn:_-bic_-nf2>
   <ETColumnDescription/>
   <ETGridData/>
   <ETMessageLog/>
   <ETRowDescription/>
   <ISVar_01xwerbet>
    <Sign>I</Sign>
    <Option>LE</Option>
    <Low>3</Low>
    <High/>
   </ISVar_01xwerbet>
  </urn:_-bic_-nf2>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am not sure if it is the missing blank header tag, which I can't seem to be able to add with basic PHP (I can add a header, but adding a blank header seems to be the hard part). Or if it is the different prefixes (ns1/urn or soapenv/SOAP-ENV) but I am starting going insane over this. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP request is fine. `ns1`/`urn` and `soapenv`/`SOAP-ENV` are just prefixes representing the namespace. Different Webservice engines generate their namespace prefixes differently and a Webservice must expect them.

SOAP header is not a mandatory thing for a webservice, but if your service expects it, you should provide that.

I would suggest you talk to the service provider about what went wrong with the request, and if thats not possible, use a SOAP testing tool, like [SOAPui](http://www.soapui.org/).

To Create an empty SOAP header, try

```
$header =new SoapHeader('urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style', null);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there a way to make a blank SOAP header?

Comment: i am getting a fatal error :-( thanks though, trying something else

Comment: Any solution for the above-mentioned issue? I am facing the same issue. I need to consume SAP Pi Webservice with wsp policy tags in wsdl. Any help would be appreciated.